# Getting an error when trying to install wifi driver from manufacturer CD on raspberry pi debian wheezy

Tags: debian, wireless, driver

I'm getting an error: authentication requested [root] for make driver ./install line 18: 4664 illegal instruction su -c make
Compile make driver error: 132, Please check error message

when attempting to install a linux driver for:

[Esky 150Mbps WIFI MINI USB WIRELESS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058XSZGU)

I tried to look for error code "132" as it says in the error message above inside the Makefile however there were no error codes defined in the makefile.

Is there something I am doing terribly wrong here? Perhaps this particular wifi dongle doesn't have a driver for ARM boards like Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Are you definitely installing the ARM driver?

Comment: I'm installing what's on the CD under the "Linux" directory.  But to be honest, I'm not certain if it's for ARM.  Separately I'm having trouble finding the driver downoads website for this particular Esky dongle. Would appreciate it if someone could direct me there as well.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do `sudo make`.

Comment: I would suggest looking for a reputable free (as in freedom) driver for the device. Not a manufacturer one and certainly not one that's trying to override system security in a script.